# what are the chances of losing a 31.5% chance win bet 14 times in a row?

Tags: probability

*what are the chances of losing a 31.5% chance to win bet, 14 times in a row?* i have tried to work it out but I am not sure how to solve this, help would be much aprecciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Chances of losing a coin flip 14 times in a row is $(0.5)^{14}$. Where does 0.5 come from?